# Save billing and shipping field data on "Pay for order" page Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Inspired by: [Display billing and shipping fields in “Pay to order” page Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882391/display-billing-and-shipping-fields-in-pay-to-order-page-woocommerce)

How can I update the billing and shipping data in the customer's account / profile and in the meta order?

or maybe perform the action that comments @Outsource WordPress **(You can then update the order meta values via AJAX call (by adding a new button).**

```
<!-- Display Information -->
<h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<address>
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_billing_address( __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>
    <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--email"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</address>

<h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<address>
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_shipping_address( __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>
</address>

<!-- Form -->
<h3><?php _e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $order ); ?>
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <?php
    $fields = WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        $field_name = $key;

        if ( is_callable( array( $order, 'get_' . $field_name ) ) ) {
            $field['value'] = $order->{"get_$field_name"}( 'edit' );
        } else {
            $field['value'] = $order->get_meta( '_' . $field_name );
        }   
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $field['value'] );
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $order ); ?>

<h3><?php _e( 'Shipping details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_shipping_form', $order ); ?>
<div class="woocommerce-shipping-fields__field-wrapper">
    <?php
    $fields = WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'shipping' );
    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        $field_name = $key;

        if ( is_callable( array( $order, 'get_' . $field_name ) ) ) {
            $field['value'] = $order->{"get_$field_name"}( 'edit' );
        } else {
            $field['value'] = $order->get_meta( '_' . $field_name );
        }   
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $field['value'] );
    }
    ?>
</div>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form', $order ); ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to save it for the user to reuse later? or for you to access it

Comment: @amarinediary Update order admin and customer profile. (billing and shipping address).